# Cannot create Html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this line of code that is supposed to create strips of an image but it won't create any html

Here is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var x;
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 5;
  console.log(x);
  var a = 1;
  var w = 50 / x;
  console.log(w);
  
  while (a <= x) {
    $('#conteneur').html("<img src='img/01.jpg' style='position: absolute; width:") + (w) + ("vw; margin:auto; top:75px; left:") + (x * a) + ("vw; object-fit: cover;'>");
    console.log(x);
    a++
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteneur"></div>
```

Should create strips of a picture but right now doesn't create anything

Comment: What does this `) + (w) + (` this suppose to do? If you are trying to concat string, loose parenthesis

Comment: You have a syntax error. If anything it should be: `.html("<img src='img/01.jpg' style='position: absolute; width:" + w + "vw; margin:auto; top:75px; left:"+ (x * a) + "vw; object-fit: cover;'>");`

Comment: that because the html is invalid, after width: you actually close the bracket. it should be something like: $('#conteneur').html("<img src='img/01.jpg' style='position: absolute; width:" +w + "vw; margin:auto; top:75px; left:" + (x * a) + "vw; object-fit: cover;'>");

Comment: Should be?:    $('#conteneur').html("<img src='img/01.jpg' style='position: absolute; width:" + w + "vw; margin:auto; top:75px; left:" + x * a + "vw; object-fit: cover;'>");

Comment: If you are including the parenthesis, make sure its inside the quotation marks, if not, then remove it is causing the errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is `>");` you forget ' and / , plus use `.append()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var x;
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 5;
  console.log(x);
  var a = 1;
  var w = 50 / x;
  console.log(w);
  var img = ("<img src='img/01.jpg' style='position: absolute; width:" + w + "vw; margin:auto; top:75px; left:" + (x * a) + "vw; object-fit: cover;' />");
  while (a <= x) {
    $('#conteneur').append(img);
    console.log(img);
    a++
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteneur"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function `.html()` will replace the html, not append to it. To do so you would use the `.append()` function.

Also you are putting the closing bracket for the `.html()` function early, so it would only set the HTML to `<img src='img/01.jpg' style='position: absolute; width:`.

This would be how you would put these two things together:

```js
$('#conteneur').append("<img src='img/01.jpg' style='position: absolute; width:" + w + "vw; margin:auto; top:75px; left:" + (x * a) + "vw; object-fit: cover;'>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var x;
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 5;
  console.log(x);
  var a = 1;
  var w = 50 / x;
  console.log(w);
  
  while (a <= x) {
    $('#conteneur').html("<img src='img/01.jpg' style='position: absolute; width:" + w + "vw; margin:auto; top:75px; left:" + (x * a) + "vw; object-fit: cover;'>");
    console.log(x);
    a++
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteneur"></div>
```

The issue is you are closing html() method.